# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException in structural typing of AnyVal

Tags: scala, structural-typing

I have the following snippet that (I think) defines a method `addNumber1(x:T):T` on a generic type `T` which is a subtype of  `AnyVal` and has a method `+(s:Int):T`.

```
def addNumber1[T <: AnyVal {def +(s:Int):T}](x:T):T = {x + 1}

addNumber1(31) // compiles but throws exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.$plus(int)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
  at .reflMethod$Method1(<console>:8)
  at .addNumber1(<console>:8)
  ... 33 elided
```

I tried adding `import scala.language.reflectiveCalls` to suppress a feature warning but still get the error.

I am able to use this when working with `AnyRef` or `Any` as below:

```
def addNumber1[T <: Any {def +(s:Int):T}](x:T):T = {x + 1}

class Foo(s:String) {def +(i:Int) = new Foo((s+1).toString)} // random code
class Bar(s:Foo) {def +(i:Int) = new Bar(new Foo(i.toString))} // random code

addNumber1(new Foo("1"))  // works
addNumber1(new Bar(new Foo("1")))  // works
addNumber1(1) // compiles but gives exception
```

Answer (score 3):

You run into an intersection of quite a few features:

1. So far as the initial stages of Scala compiler are concerned (including typechecking), `Int` does have an (overloaded) `+` method. But this "method" is treated specially by the later stages (as are all methods on `Int`, because it isn't really a class).
2. Methods called `+` and defined in Scala are translated to methods called `$plus` in bytecode, since `+` is not a legal identifier there. Since `+` on `Int` is special, as mentioned above, this doesn't apply to it. Since the structural types are implemented using Java reflection, your `addNumber1` looks somewhat like

   ```
   def addNumber1(x: Object) = x.getClass.getMethod("$plus").invoke(x, 1)
   ```
3. To call `addNumber1` on an `int`, it has to be boxed to `Integer` first, because `int` is not an object. `Integer`, not being a Scala type, doesn't have a `$plus` method. In Scala you *can* write something like `val x: Integer = ...; x + 1`, but this uses an implicit conversion which Java reflection has no idea about.

Comment: I think structural types should be implemented using Scala reflection, which has become quite stable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has nothing to do with AnyVal, AnyRef Or Any.

```
addNumber1(new Foo("1"))
```

This works because you indeed defined a Foo class that provides an implementation of def +(s:Int):T.

```
addNumber1(1)
```

This doesn't work because Integer class doesn't provide it, as is mentioned in the exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.$plus(int)
```

Comment: The problem is why it compiles.

Comment: It compiles because scala compiler "thinks" that Int does have + operator, it has to, because for example i + 1 is valid where i is of type Int.

Comment: I used AnyVal because they map to primitive Java types. The problem occurs only when using primitive Java types.

Comment: the number 31 in addNumber1(31) is not of a Java primitive type, it is of a Scala primitive type Int, and it is the source of the problem, Scala compiler  thinks Int has a + operator at compile time, this is true, but is false once Int is boxed to Integer at runtime.

Comment: That's what I meant. "the problem occurs when using (Scala types that map to) Java primitives types." Equivalently, I could have written "the problem occurs only with AnyVals", which is the title of the question. Perhaps the compiler could actually infer if its a "magic" method used in structural typing (and elsewhere).