# Generic return type in Scala structural type method

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, duck-typing, structural-typing

I'm trying to create a structural type in Scala with a method that has a generic return type. For instance, something like:

```scala
type Manipulable[T] = Any {
  def +(x: Int): T
}

def add[T <: Manipulable[T]](o: T, x: Int) = o + x

// these lines throw Exceptions
add(19.0, 3)
add(3, 3)
add(42L, 3)
```

Scala's structural types are set scoped to `AnyRef` by default, so to use the value types (Java's primitives), we prepend the `Any` before the type definition. Structural types can take type parameters, as seen above, but those type parameters cannot then be used as the types of any method value parameters. (You could have `x: => T`, but not `x: T`.)

When trying to use `add()` on a `Manipulable[Double]` or `Manipulable[Int]` (etc.), though, we get a Java `NoSuchMethodException`. Note that this only happens with methods with purely generic return types. The following structural type, for instance, works fine:

```scala
type Manipulable[T] = Any {
  def getClass (): Class[T] // Class[_] also works
  def toString() : String
}

def gc[T <: Manipulable[T]](o: T): Class[T] = o.getClass()

gc(19.0) // Class[Double] = class java.lang.Double
gc(3)    // Class[Int] = class java.lang.Integer
gc(42L)  // Class[Long] = class java.lang.Long

def str[T <: Manipulable[T]](o: T): String = o.toString()

str(19.0) // String = 19.0
str(3)    // String = 3
str(42L)  // String = 42
```

I'm guessing this is an issue with value types in Scala, because reference types seem fine:

```scala
type Manipulable[T] = Any {
  def substring(x: Int) : T
}

def ss[T <: Manipulable[T]](o: T, x: Int) = o.substring(x)

ss("hello, world", 7) // prints "world"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315310/getting-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-in-structural-typing-of-anyval

Comment: Any reason for using the weak and slow structural types instead of using a **typeclass** instead?

Comment: @DmytroMitin you're right, this is a duplicate of that question. I've marked it as such but will keep it up, because I couldn't find that other question while searching. Maybe my alternate wording / problem statement will help people find it more easily.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez because I'm trying to match on Java primitives, not create a new type class.

Comment: @awwsmm do you at least know what a **typeclass** is?